# How to Invoke API in WSO2_AM from WSO2_ESB Proxy Service

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I have published an API in `WSO2AM` and the url shown in store is `https://{ip}:8243/phoneverify/1.0.0`

Now what I'm trying to do is call this from ESB Proxy service (which will later be invoked by a scheduler) as follows,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="a"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <http method="get"
                     uri-template="https://{ip}:8243/phoneverify/1.0.0/CheckPhoneNumber">
                  <timeout>
                     <duration>30000</duration>
                     <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
                  </timeout>
               </http>
               <property name="Authorization"
                         value="Bearer aaa4663b5851e06f2f1bc6e871fd20b7"
                         scope="axis2"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

But when I try this it gives `org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Read timed out` and in the server

```
[2015-03-20 08:50:48,481]  INFO - LogMediator To: /services/a.aHttpSoap12Endpoint, WSAction: urn:mediate, SOAPAction: urn:mediate, MessageID: urn:uuid:ce224d0e-f158-458c-b0be-ffeb09198e47, Direction: request, Envelope: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
[2015-03-20 08:50:48,500]  INFO - TimeoutHandler This engine will expire all callbacks after : 120 seconds, irrespective of the timeout action, after the specified or optional timeout


[2015-03-20 08:50:49,289] ERROR - TargetHandler I/O error: Host name verification failed for host : {ip}
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Host name verification failed for host : 52.74.66.119
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.http.conn.ClientSSLSetupHandler.verify(ClientSSLSetupHandler.java:152)
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:285)
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.isAppInputReady(SSLIOSession.java:380)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:118)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:160)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:342)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:320)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:280)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:106)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:604)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[2015-03-20 08:50:49,320]  WARN - EndpointContext Endpoint : AnonymousEndpoint will be marked SUSPENDED as it failed
[2015-03-20 08:50:49,320]  WARN - EndpointContext Suspending endpoint : AnonymousEndpoint - current suspend duration is : 30000ms - Next retry after : Fri Mar 20 08:51:19 UTC 2015
```

I could invoke the API using `Chrome Advanced Rest Client`. Therefore what am I doing wrong in, invoking this through the proxy service?

Comment: What is `/services/TesAM` ? also could replace `{ip}` for real value and remove `<timeout>` just for testing. Enable Tcpmon to check outgoing request message of WSO2 ESB to WSO2 AM.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, log is corrected, {ip} is purposely replace for the original

Comment: Ah,  why `<property name="Authorization" value="Bearer aaa4663b5851e06f2f1bc6e871fd20b7" scope="transport"/>` is inside of `<endpoint>` ?, Should be between `<log level="full"/>` and  `<send>`, no?.

Comment: It's the user token which should be attached to make the call. And I tested this with Advance Rest Client with attaching the token as Authorization header.

Comment: I tried with what you suggested, replacing the property between `log` and `send`. But the same error occurs :(

Comment: Try converting the incoming SOAP message to REST message before of `send` mediator. Your API is expecting a REST message.

Comment: Could you please point me any example, how to convert SOAP to REST inside ESB?

Comment: I think this is a config issue. Please try out the config suggested in https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-2089

Comment: @Sajith Thanks for pointing out the config issue. I changed the default value to `AllowAll` and it worked, though there's a new error in `WSO2AM` side `APIAuthenticationHandler API authentication failure
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APISecurityException: Required OAuth credentials not provided`

Comment: Are you sending the Authorization header with your request?
 -H "Authorization :Bearer <access-token>"

Comment: @Sajith, I am sending it as a property, please see I have mentioned it in the question, `<property name="Authorization"
                         value="Bearer aaa4663b5851e06f2f1bc6e871fd20b7"
                         scope="axis2"/>`

Comment: You have to send that as a header. Use the header mediator for that  <header name="Authorization" value="xxxxxx" scope="transport"/>

Comment: @Sajith, thanks that work as well. If you add the solution as the answer, I am happy to mark it is THE answer :)

Comment: Thanks Isuru, will do :)

Answer (score 0):

If your API is expecting a REST/JSon message, in your Proxy (WSO2 ESB) you should add `<property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>` before of `<send>`.
If your API is expecting REST/XML, then use `application/xml`.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

For the "Host name verification failed for host" exception, please try out the config suggested in wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-2089

And also, in your proxy service, you have to use the header mediator for setting  Authorization header.

```
<header name="Authorization" value="xxxxxx" scope="transport"/>
```

Comment: Hi Sajith and Isuru, `<header name="Authorization" value="xxxxxx" scope="transport"/>` and `<property name="Authorization" value="Bearer xyz" scope="transport"/>` are correct. For info, check this [link](http://nuwanwimalasekara.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/how-to-add-http-basic-authentication.html).